# Jquery code generated inside a PHP while loop returning NaN for the calculation

Tags: php, jquery

I have a lot of input fields on the page and 47 rows in the table
I am using a php while loop to generate the jquery code and to create an auto increment ID number for the row

I am then trying to calculate the value of various columns in each row when the values in the input field on the corresponding row is changed however I keep getting NaN returned.

I have looked across similar issues mentioned on SO but no suggested answer seems to work in my case

Here is my PHP Code for creating the table

```
<?php  $id = 1; 
  do {
    $col1 = $id.'a';  
    $col2 = $id.'b';
    $col3 = $id.'c';
    $col4 = $id.'d';
    $col5 = $id.'e';
    $col6 = $id.'f';
    $col7 = $id.'g';
    $col8 = $id.'h';
    $col9 = $id.'i';
    $col10 = $id.'j';
    $col11 = $id.'k';
    $col12 = $id.'l';

?>
  <tr id="<?php echo "calculate$id";?>" style="border:0px solid #ffffff;">
    <td class="tg-0lax"><?php echo $res['process_type_code'].'  '.$res['process_type'];?></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col1;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['rebagging_cost'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col2;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['rebagging_process_loss'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col3;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['sifting_seiving_cost'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col4;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center"width="10px" value="<?php echo $res['sifting_seiving_process_loss'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col5;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['blending_cost'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col6;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['blending_process_loss'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col7;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['cracking_cost'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col8;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['cracking_process_loss'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col9;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['milling_cost'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col10;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['milling_process_loss'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col11;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['heat_treatment_cost'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="<?php echo $col12;?>" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" value="<?php echo $res['heat_treatment_process_loss'];?>" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><input id="totalprocesscostton<?php echo $id;?>" readonly="readonly" type="text" style="width:50px; border:none;text-align:center" /></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><?php echo $res['total_process_cost_kg'];?></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><?php echo $res['total_process_loss_pct'];?></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><?php echo $res['processed_or_finished'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php $id++; } while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));?>
```

Here is the PHP code that is creating the Jquery code for each row

```
<?php 
    $row = 1;
    $cola = $row.'a';  
    $colb = $row.'b';
    $colc = $row.'c';
    $cold = $row.'d';
    $cole = $row.'e';
    $colf = $row.'f';
    $colg = $row.'g';
    $colh = $row.'h';
    $coli = $row.'i';
    $colj = $row.'j';
    $colk = $row.'k';
    $coll = $row.'l';
do {
echo "<script>
      $(\"#calculate$row\").click(function() {      
          var a = $(\"#".$cola."\").val();
          var b = $(\"#".$colb."\").val();
          var c = $(\"#".$colc."\").val();
          var d = $(\"#".$cold."\").val();
          var e = $(\"#".$cole."\").val();
          var f = $(\"#".$colf."\").val();
          var g = $(\"#".$colg."\").val();
          var h = $(\"#".$colh."\").val();
          var i = $(\"#".$coli."\").val();
          var j = $(\"#".$colj."\").val();
          var k = $(\"#".$colk."\").val();
          var l = $(\"#".$coll."\").val();
          var totalprocesscostton = parseInt(a) + parseInt(c) + parseInt(e) + parseInt(g) + parseInt(i) + parseInt(k);
          $(\"#totalprocesscostton".$row."\").val(totalprocesscostton);

      });
    </script>";
$row++;
}while ($row !=47);
?>
```

Hope someone can shed some light on this
** Edit : Added updated image with better description

[Here is a screenshot of the table with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wozTC.jpg)

Comment: you have too much unnecessary code, it can be simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at `parseInt` return value: An integer number parsed from the given string. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.

You could use a ternary operator to ensure an int is always set.

```
var a = ( isNaN( parseInt( $("#".$cola."\").val() ) ) ? 0 : parseInt($("#".$cola."\").val()) );
```

Comment: ok its now giving me a value of 0 in the calculated value field

Comment: it should only set a value of 0 if the .val() results in NAN. If this isnt the case my code is incorrectly interpreting a number as NAN.

Comment: I just dont understand why its giving me NaN as the only values in the text field are numerical digits

Comment: As mentioned, NAN will be returned if: `If the first character cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.` I suggest you print each value with `console.log(a,b,c,d,e,f,g...)` and ensure that all these properties are valid integers

Comment: Im getting 0 for every value .. even the first input field which is strange because the value pulled from the database is 10 .. I have even used php's intval on the data being inserted to ensure its seen as an integer but for some reason that has no effect

Comment: Getting False , 1
Just to add I've also manually entered 10 in the input field value in the html source before i did this so its not pulling php data now

Comment: Getting 10 returned in log

Comment: do you know what type 10 is? If its a string, does it have any white space?

Comment: Try running this, should work:

`var a = (
 isNaN( parseInt( $("#".$cola."\").val() ) ) ? 0 : parseInt($("#".$cola."\").val())
);
console.log(a);`

Comment: its definitely integer I've just done <?php $val = '10'; echo intval($val);?> no whitespace before value either

Comment: its where the JS picks it up that its not an int. It's a string that needs casting to an int. Does the isNaN code work?

Comment: cool, just use that in place of the var assignments and it will work

Comment: I see why the first code suggestion didnt work. Number.isInt isn't a string at that point. I assumed the fn would attempt to cast. But it just checks type

Comment: Just replaced other instances and calculating fine now .. many thanks :)

Comment: it doesnt take into account numbers with a decimal ? how can this be fixed ?